# Application level variabled in asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms

How can i get all application level variables in any sub applications as well

I have 3 to 4 application inside one website in IIS, Now application variables are for each application but i want to set and reset from any application page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the web.config of each application you would like to share session data for, add the following HTTP module:

```
<httpModules>
   <add name="SharedSessionModule" type="Femiani.Web.Modules.SharedSessionModule, 
                                         Femiani.Web.Modules.SharedSessionModule"/>
</httpModules>
```

set your application name:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ApplicationName" value="SharedWeb"/>
</appSettings>
```